# What is AuthUser in SoapClient.ConnectorProperty("AuthUser") VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, soap-client

I've a C# webservice deployed on production.
I was able to access the service on localhost without any authentication but now after deployment to production it gives me error :

**connection failed or server refused connection**

So after research i came to know about AuthUser but i don't know which username and password to be send.
Which user name should i pass as value in AuthUser to access my webservice on production??

My Code in VBA :

```
SoapClient.MSSoapInit ("http://mywebsite.com/WS/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl")
SoapClient.ConnectorProperty("AuthUser") = "abc"
SoapClient.ConnectorProperty("AuthPassword") = "123"
Call SoapClient.HelloWorld()
```

Comment: Ask the server administrator. The error has little to do with authentication though, seems like a network issue. Can you visit that url from your browser?

Comment: Yes i am able to access the URL. It shows methods list as it shows in localhost